# Not able to connect to Azure mysql database on mysql workbench

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am Not able to connect to Azure MySQL database using MySQL workbench. 
using ClearDB[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to azure graphice interface and to access to your mysql database server then to take the copy the server name and put it in the host
and the connection name it will be your user name and you have to use the same password which you create in mysql server
and in addition to this try follow this link it will help you to understand more with all of the detailes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/connect-workbench

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).